# Solution for location given relative distance of receiver

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, parameter-estimation

Sorry if this is not the proper place to ask the question, couldn't find any other relevant forum (perhaps dsp exchange).

I am looking into finding a most likely position of a source given  recordings from 4 microphones with unknown locations. I have the speech data recorded on the microphones. Cross-correlation gives me an estimate of the delay between the recordings and knowing the sound velocity in air, I can find the relative distances between the microphones. So, I get something like 5m between microphones 1 and 2, 3.5m between 2 and 3 and so on (6 distance estimates in all). That means f.ex. microphone 2 could be anywhere on a circle with a radius of 5m and centered around 1st microphone and so with the other pair combinations.
Is there a way (optimization method) to give an estimate of the most probable location of the source relative to the microphone positions ? It looks a very under-determined system, but I was wondering whether one can arrive at a likelihood estimate ?

Appreciate your help and sorry again if I am posting in the wrong forum.

Edit:

Thank to @John Omielan for pointing out the error of 'under-determined vs. over-determined'.
Maybe I should add that the distance measurements are prone to small errors and not absolute.

Comment: FYI, based on what you wrote and if I'm understanding it correctly, it's actually an over-determined system as, assuming you're not considering height, you have just $2$ values to determine, but with $6$ distance equations involving the co-ordinates.

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course.

Comment: How did you decide that microphone 2 lies on some circle around microphone 1, &c? A time difference between a pair of microphones gives you a hyperbola with the microphones at its foci on which the source lies, but that time difference only gives you a _minimum_ distance between the foci.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Do you have any reference (paper) on this ?